On Windows, how to connect from JupyterLab to SQL Server as Active Directory user?
We have an instance of JupyterLab running on Windows, and we want to connect to a data source on SQL Server following the reference below:

https://sfoteini.github.io/blog/connect-to-azure-sql-database-using-python-and-jupyter-notebook/

We have installed the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server v18 on Windows, and the following iPython statement completed OK in the .ipynb file.
import pyodbc
print("Imported pyodgc")

For the next, we need to construct the connection string and try to get the first happy pass connection. The reference above provided the following sample source code.
# Establish the connection
server = '<server>.database.windows.net'
database = '<database>'
username = '<username>'
password = '<password>'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=' + driver + ';SERVER=' +
    server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + database +
    ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)
print(conn)
conn.close()

If use the above source code, we expect to get the connection string DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=<server>.database.windows.net;PORT=1433;DATABASE=<database>;UID=<username>;PWD=<password>.
However, in our organization, we connect to the SQL Server by the user's Active Directory credential. For example, we grant access to a user DOMAIN\username, and then the user logs in Windows and starts the SQL Server Management Studio. In this way, the program is running as the user DOMAIN\username. Therefore, the client will get connected without being asked for username and password.
We are trying to translate the above way of working into Jupyter context and make it work. So, instead, we constructed the following connection string.
DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=<server>.database.windows.net;PORT=1433;DATABASE=<database>
However, we got the following error. And, it seems that the driver considers user as empty string and got a login failure.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 1
----> 1 conn = pyodbc.connect(connect_str)

InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]
[SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] 
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456)")


We wonder if it is possible to make a connection from Jupyter to SQL Server using the running user's Active Directory credential, and how.
We appreciate any hints and suggestions.

Is the JupyterLab process executing with the authentication context of the domain user? Based on DSN and Connection String Keywords and Attributes have you tried using the Trusted_Connection keyword?

In case it's something else... if you have access to the SQL Server instance's ERRORLOG search for the Error 18456 Login Failure events, take note of their State number(s) and compare against the State numbers published in MSSQLSERVER_18456 to determine the actual cause.

Thanks to @AlwaysLearning, we resolved the issue by using Trusted_Connection=yes in the connection string.

Made a working connection by the following connection string:
DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}; SERVER=<server>; DATABASE=<database>; Trusted_Connection=yes.
So, thanks to @AlwaysLearning, the key of the solution is Trusted_Connection.
